# ssh server stops running after the first successful connection ends whilst running sshd directly

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

When I do `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p2222` and then connect to the newly created SSH server sshd stops running after the first connection ends.

I mean, I get that `sudo service sshd start` would prob be better but still, is there a way to make `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd` work?

I'm running `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`.

Comment: Your command is doing exactly what your telling it to do, your starting a process, when the connection ends that process also ends. If you want a service process that always exists. Start the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `-d` does.

> `-d`
> Debug mode. The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background. The server also will not `fork(2)` and **will only process one connection. This option is only intended for debugging for the server.** Multiple `-d` options increase the debugging level. Maximum is 3.

<sup>(source: [`man 8 sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#d), emphasis mine)</sup>

> is there a way to make `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd` work?

It does work, but it deamonizes itself. Even with `-d` it does work *as described*. If you want `sshd` to process more than one connection then don't use `-d`. If you want it not to become a deamon, use [`-D`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#D). If you want debug info, use [`LogLevel`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#LogLevel). If you want to see this info in the terminal, use [`-e`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#e).

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -D -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 -e
```